# Tab panel with items that don't fit the width of the panel

Tags: extjs, tabpanel, extjs6-classic

I am facing an issue where the tabs don't fit the entire width of the panel, and the user has to scroll to the right to view the rightmost tabs.

To see what I mean, please can go to this Sencha [example](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#advanced-tabs), add enough tabs to enable the scrolling in the tab header.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to make the tabs wrap rather than having the scrolling effect?
2. Is there a plugin that can be used to create a dropdown menu/list with all the tabs or perhaps with the tabs that are not visible on the top right corner?
3. Is there a way to configure the table panel such that when I click on the > button on the right side to scroll the tab items, they scroll enough to make the next item visible instead of scrolling in small increments?

Ultimately, I could simulate the tab panel by adding a toolbar and buttons, and using the cardlayout. That would be my plan B.

Thank you

Update: I can set the flex: 1 property for each tab (inside tabConfig). I still have to figure out tooltips and enable the elipsis on the longer tabs that get chopped off.

Comment: 2. question: you can try this config on your `tabpanel`: `tabBar: {layout: { overflowHandler: 'menu'}}`

Comment: It works nicely: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3fqn. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Please create your answer.

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome!

Comment: One issue though, when I select an item from the menu, it is not selected at the top. I will explore more. But this is good - it is the solution I wanted.

Comment: About this last issue I am a little sceptical, the difference between `menu` and `scroller` `overflowHandler` is that with `menu` the tabs that don't fit on the `tabBar` will be rendered into a menu - they are not rendered on the `tabBar`, and therefore I don't think it's possible to see one of these selected on the `tabBar`. But keep me posted if you find a solution!

Comment: I read the extjs code and it doesn't seem to be possible without a bigger coding effort. There is a method: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.tab.Bar.html#method-ensureTabVisible, but it works only when the scroller is used. I guess one could a custom dropdown button and handle the menu items manually.

Comment: Could be quite complicated. Maybe you could try hiding all tabs before the current selected one, and see what happens. It is possible that ExtJS will redraw the tab bar and the currently selected will be visible. I don't know how it plays out and definitely has drawbacks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `tabBar` config for tabpanels, [see here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.tab.Panel.html#cfg-tabBar). Within this you can set layout properties, including `overflowHandler`, and one possible value is `menu`. This will do what you asked for in question 2. Add this config to `tabpanel` definition:

```
tabBar: {
    layout: {
        overflowHandler: 'menu'
    }
}
```